# How to deploy war file on two instance of tomcat using gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: linux, shell, gitlab, continuous-integration, tomcat9

I have a spring boot web app project on gitlab, which is needed to be deployed on two remote instances of Tomcat servers using CI/CD. After quick research I have found [this article](https://www.fosstechnix.com/deploy-war-to-tomcat-using-gitlab-ci-pipeline/). According to the article all necessary components are installed and the following gitlab-ci.yml file was created:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

maven-build:
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.war
Deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cp /home/gitlab-runner/builds/76XAQ_K8/0/l.furkat/testservice/target/testservice.war /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps
```

But in the script above one can deploy the app on one instance.

**How can I deploy the project on two instances?**

Any hint or navigation is appreciated.

Comment: Just add another `cp` command? I'm not sure I see your problem.

Comment: As @sytech stated, would be adding another script.  Since you stated "two remote instatances", just note that you'd need to set up priv/pub keys on those server and would be using scp instead of cp.